Is "last couple of months had been very busy" correct?
I’m not sure if I need to put had or have in the sentence.

Last couple of months had been very busy.


It depends entirely on the context, which you haven't specified.

This question is similar to: Past simple, past perfect. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

We should have the definite article the.
As the reference point is now, we use the present have:

[The] last couple of months have been very busy.

If we are referring to some time in the past, we use had:
The last couple of months before the closing of the last financial year's accounts had been very busy.
